# How to create a node using the structure definition if the integer value is passed to a function?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

The Definition of the structure is as follows.

```cpp
//Structure of the linked list node is as follows:

struct Node {
  
    int data;
    struct Node* next;

    Node(int x) {
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
    }

};
```

I have to complete this function which I have completed this way. I am trying to create a Node using the newData parameter passed in the function definition. But it shows the error which I have attached below.

```cpp
// function inserts the data in front of the list
                                                                                                
Node* insertAtBegining(Node *head, int newData) {   
    //Your code here

    struct Node* newNode(newData);
    struct Node* temp;

    temp=head;
    head=newNode;
    newNode->next=temp;

}
```

I get this error while I am create a node by passing newData as parameter to `struct Node *newNode(newData);`

In function `Node* insertAtBegining(Node*, int)`:

> prog.cpp:67:32: error: invalid conversion from int to Node* [-fpermissive]
>
> struct Node *newNode(newData);

Thank You for your help.

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need the `struct` keyword when defining variables (or pointers).

Comment: Your function lies.  The function signature says the function returns a `Node *`, but your function returns nothing.  Either change the return type to `void` (to indicate no return values) or return a `Node *` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor returns a Node, not a Node*, so when you try to initialize newNode, the compiler thinks you're trying to create a pointer using an int. Instead you should be expecting your constructor to give you a Node:

```
Node newNode(newData);
```

Comment: I understood the solution. Thank You so much for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `insertAtBegining()` implementation needs to create a new `Node` object.  You aren't doing that.  Right after your teacher's `Your code here` comment, your attempt has defined a "`Node` pointer" variable (whose type is `Node*`), but your attempt hasn't initialized that to any `Node` object (data that would have been passed to an object's constructor isn't the same as the object itself).

Also, you don't need to keep repeating `struct` that way that us old guys used to do with old-fashioned C code.

Lastly, you seem to also want to return the list's new head node back to the function's caller, but are unclear how you want to achieve that.  There are two ways. The way that your code seems to be leaning towards is returning the new head in the same `head` parameter. In that case, it should look like this:

```
void insertAtBegining(Node** head, int newData)
{
//Your code here
    Node* newNode = new Node(newData);
    Node* temp;
    temp = *head;
    *head = newNode;
    newNode->next = temp;
}
```

(The `head` parameter could also have been a "reference to a `Node*`", instead of this "pointer to a `Node*`", by making appropriate changes to the code.)

The second option (which maintains your teacher's recommended function signature) is to return the new head via the function's return value:

```
Node* insertAtBegining(Node* head, int newData)
{
//Your code here
    Node* newNode = new Node(newData);
    newNode->next = head;
    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the detailed solution. I am actually new to the concept of structures and linked lists so I have not that much understanding of these concepts. But I have understood your solution. Thank You so much.